# pragmatically open side navigation menu by tapping on a bottom navigation bar in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-getx

I have a bottom navigation bar with four items that changes from a getx controller. I want to open a navigation drawer when I click on the last navigation bar item. I have a void function that calls on the onTap function of the BottomNavigationBar and looks like this:  How would i approach such a problem?

```
 void onTabTapped(int index) {
      
      if (controller.selectedIndex == 3) {
        setState(() {
          print('clicked fourth item');
        });
        
      }
      else{
        controller.selectedIndex = index;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following function;

```
 Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
```

Another way is that you can use ScaffoldKey ;

```
Scaffold(
key: _scaffoldKey,
...
```

call drawer;

```
onTap(){
_scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();
}
```

**EDIT:**
Have a look on full code snippet; Note that I have 3 elements in my navigation bar that's why I passed 2 to last index. It works fine.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  bool loadingApp = true;
  int _currentIndex = 0 ;
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  void _onTabTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index;
    });

    if (_currentIndex == 2){
      _scaffoldKey.currentState!.openDrawer();
    }
  }
```

....

Scaffold part;

```
return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
```

.......

navigation bar ;

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    onTap: _onTabTapped ,
    currentIndex: _currentIndex,
```

Comment: Thank you. But how do i call the Drawer when i click a specific item in the bottom navigation bar? The on onTabTapped function is not printing when i am on the third item meaning it is not working somehow even if i put the openDrawer function